# Passing role type to Laratrust form database variable

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laratrust

I am using Laratrust with laravel to display records from the database according to roles. Every record has a role type field (example to table below).

[image]

In my blade view, I want to display them as the code (the variable is called `$types`).

```
<select name="type" id="" class="form-control">
    @foreach ($types as $type)
        @role($type->role)
        <option value="{{ $type->id }}">
            {{ $type->name }} {{ $type->role }}
        </option>
        @endrole
    @endforeach
</select>
```

It shows nothing. My data is correct. I tried to write the roles type by hand, and it worked. If I left the `@role()` empty, it shows an error, so it is not a problem of the role interpreted before the variable is passed. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the variable type was String
and @role only worked with arrays so I add an accessor in the model to decode the data before getting it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
<select name="type" id="" class="form-control">
    @foreach ($types as $type)
        @if(auth()->check() && auth()->user()->hasRole($type->role))
            <option value="{{ $type->id }}">
                {{ $type->name }} {{ implode(', ', json_decode($type->role)) }}
            </option>
        @endif
    @endforeach
</select>
```